# Protractor : Identify invisible element.

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

When i run test in protractor , i got error message saying 
Message :
 Failed: Element not visible

Is there anyway to find which element is not visible ?

> Stack:
>        ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
>             (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
>             (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>
> Conf:

```
{

  seleniumServerJar: null,
  seleniumPort: null,
  chromeDriver: null,
  seleniumArgs: [],
  sauceUser: null,
  sauceKey: null,
  seleniumAddress: null,
  suites: {
    login:'./common/login.js',
    create_item:'./businessScenarios/create_an_item.js',
    regressionTest:[
    './common/login.js',
   './businessScenarios/create_an_item.js', 
   ]
  },
  allScriptsTimeout:3000000,
  capabilities:{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['no-sandbox','no-default-browser-check','no-first-run','disable-default-apps']
    }
  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors:true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 3000000,
    // onComplete will be called just before the driver quits.
    onComplete: null,
    // If true, display spec names.
    isVerbose: false,
    // If true, include stack traces in failures.
    includeStackTrace: true
  },
  params: {
    login: false,
    uname:'user',
    pwd:'pwd'
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
            savePath: './protractor-result',
            takeScreenshots: false
        })
      );
   },
   rootElement: 'body'
}
```

> spec.js

```
        browser.executeScript("$('#toast-container').remove();");
        element.all(by.css('.dx-datagrid-table')).all(by.css('.dx-data-row')).get(0).click().then(function() {
            element.all(by.css('.dx-row.dx-data-row.dx-column-lines.bold_item.dx-selection')).first().click().click().then(function() {
                   var currentUrl = browser.driver.getCurrentUrl();
                expect(currentUrl).toMatch('/itemMaintenance/edit');
                browser.sleep(2000);
                browser.executeScript("$('#toast-container').remove();");

                var family = element.all(by.css('.selectize-input')).get(4);
                family.isPresent().then(function(value) {
                    if (value) {
                        family.click().then(function() {
                            browser.sleep(12222);
                            element.all(by.css('.selectize-input input')).get(4).sendKeys(121212);
                            browser.sleep(10000);
                            var content = element.all(by.css('.selectize-dropdown-content')).get(0);
                            content.all(by.css('.option')).get(1).click();
                            browser.sleep(2000);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
            browser.sleep(1000);
        });
```

Comment: check `isDisplayed` it returns false when the element exists but is not visible

Comment: @maurycy Is there anyway ,that we can get to know about invisible element in Stack Trace Info. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element you click should be visible and should be on the page (not conditional appearance or randomness) then you can do it this way:

```
browser.executeScript("$('#toast-container').remove();");
element.all(by.css('.dx-datagrid-table')).all(by.css('.dx-data-row')).get(0).click().then(function () {
    element.all(by.css('.dx-row.dx-data-row.dx-column-lines.bold_item.dx-selection')).first().click().click().then(function () {
        var currentUrl = browser.driver.getCurrentUrl();
        expect(currentUrl).toMatch('/itemMaintenance/edit');
        browser.sleep(2000);
        browser.executeScript("$('#toast-container').remove();");
        var family = element.all(by.css('.selectize-input')).get(4);

        //added-start
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(family), 5000, 'Element was not visible in time');
        //added-end

        family.click().then(function () {
            browser.sleep(12222);
            element.all(by.css('.selectize-input input')).get(4).sendKeys(121212);
            browser.sleep(10000);
            var content = element.all(by.css('.selectize-dropdown-content')).get(0);
            content.all(by.css('.option')).get(1).click();
            browser.sleep(2000);
        });
    });
    browser.sleep(1000);
});
```